# Can Ubidots send one Nodemcu data to another nodemcu?

Tags: server, mqtt, iot, esp8266, nodemcu

I am trying to connect multiple Nodemcu with Ubidots and finally add one master device that can read all the from other slave devices. Can I do it directly from Ubidots IoT Platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it directly with [Ubidots](https://ubidots.com/). I recommend you to manage your data using MQTT as a communication protocol. Check out [Ubidots Docs](https://ubidots.com/docs/hw/#mqtt) for detailed info.

You have to use the [publish example](https://github.com/ubidots/ubidots-mqtt-esp/tree/master/examples/publishToBusiness) for the slave nodes, and from the master node, you must use the [subscribe example](https://github.com/ubidots/ubidots-mqtt-esp/tree/master/examples/subscribeToBusiness) to get the values from the different variables.

The [code of this project](https://ubidots.com/blog/rgb-smart-planter/) can serve as a reference for you to subscribe to multiple variables at the same time.

Comment: Currently I am sending data to Ubidots by using variable ID. Is it possible by accessing or exchanging variable ID?

Comment: If you are using ID variable it is because your example uses HTTP instead of MQTT. This way it would also work but not in the right way. In order for your project to work as it should, I recommend you to migrate your code to MQTT following the examples I sent you previously.

Comment: What are the good examples for Nodemcu to send data to Ubidots using MQTT?

Comment: All the examples provided in the first comment will help you to get started with Ubidots over MQTT. For more projects ideas, you can visit the [Ubidots Help Center](https://help.ubidots.com/en/) o [Ubidots Blog](https://ubidots.com/blog/).